# window.onclick function not removing class if target contains a particular class

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have a modal function set up that basically adds a class and displays when the modal trigger button has been clicked. I also have a close button that hides the modal and removes the class but I wanted to do this on a window event too.

This is what I have so far but doesn't seem to be working..

```
window.onclick = (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains === 'modal--active') {
        e.classList.remove('modal--active');
    }
}
```

So basically if the modal contains a class of modal--active, remove the class when clicking anywhere in the browser window.

P.s I tried removing the strictly equals ' === ' to just ' = ' but no luck.

Any help would be awesome thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to the `e.target.classList.contains('modal--active')`, [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) it's a function, not a property of the DOM node.

Full code:

```
window.onclick = (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('modal--active')) {
        e.target.classList.remove('modal--active');
    }
}
```